# Google Calendar API . Can I write to a users calendar when the user isn't logged in?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-client

This may seem like a totally idiotic question but I am looking at writing a web app/service that will utilize google's calendar API's and I needed to see if I have the ability to write to a users calendar when the user isn't logged into there google account.  I couldn't find any clear documentation that illustrated whether or not I could do this or not.  I pictured the authorization process something the user agrees to when they sign up for my site and then my app can go add things to there google calendar. Does anyone know if this is possible?  If so, can someone hook me up with a link that illustrates how that works?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking about "logged in" wrong.

Because web connections don't persist between requests, any web-site or web-service is checking headers such as the `Authorization` header and/or `Cookie` header (depending on what authorisation method is used), with each and every request and matching the request to a user.

Hence logging in* means that the web client (browser or whatever) is set to use the details that relate to a particular user in making the request.

When you use the API, the authorisation information you send, is performing the same job. As such, when the user is using your API they **are** logged in through your API, whether they're logged in through a web page or other application or not.

E.g.:

My web browser is currently logged into google to an account I use for work stuff.

My mail client is logged into google calendar to an account I use for private stuff.

When I look at google calendar, I see that I don't have any calendars (I don't use it on my work account).

When I look at Thunderbird, I see my calendars.

If I peek at the traffic being sent by the browser and mail client, on both I see headers like:

```
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=...stuff I'm not going to share or it would help you impersonate me
```

So, I'm "logged in" on Thunderbird because the code using the API logs me in itself.

Indeed, the same application can access multiple accounts and be "logged in" to all of them, as long as it has the authentication details to do so.

*Strictly, some would argue that "logged in" isn't the correct term at all, and refers to different sorts of access mechanism where there is state on the connection. Whatever about that opinion, we use the metaphor of being or not being logged in, because users understand it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is yes. Use OAuth 2 and the Authorization Code flow (web server flow), with offline enabled. Store the refresh tokens (which last indefinitely until the user has revoked), and you'll be able to upload events to Google Calendar even when the user isn't currently logged in.

More info: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline

Credits to Ryan Boyd for this note.